# reloading a ng-include template on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list of links and when I click on each of them, I call a file with ng-include. All I want is to reload the files when I re-click on those files. 
This is the list of links:

```
<ul class="list-group  gray-bg">
   <li class="list-group-item link" ng-click="show=1">something</li>
   <li class="list-group-item link" ng-click="show=1">something</li>
</ul>
```

And the section that changes in each click is like this:

```
<div ng-show="show==1">
    <div ng-include src="'templates/feature-descriptions/shop.phtml'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="show==2">
    <div ng-include src="'templates/feature-descriptions/no-credit.phtml'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you are going to achieve by reloading it..It doesn't make sense in that way..do you have controller attached to those template?

Comment: No I don't have any controller. I used some animation (with animation.css) and when I re-click on those links, those animation won't work since all those files are reloaded already. (maybe I'm using reloading wrongly. I want to refresh those part)

Comment: possible solution for you case would be using `ng-if` like `<div ng-if="show==1">
    <div ng-include src="'templates/feature-descriptions/shop.phtml'"></div>
</div>` & then your ng-click would be `ng-click="show=0;show=1"` made `0` for just fake change to redraw `ng-if` div

Comment: That worked! The solution was easy and nice. Thank you.

Comment: I've added an answer..please do look at it..It has some more explaination..please to mark it correct with upvote..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you could have `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` directive that will help you to make animate your div as it is going to add or remove on the basis of the expression given in `ng-if` directive.

As you want to refresh the ng-include element I'd suggest you have first set the dummy value to `show` scope variable and then give actual value to `show` so that the div will get remove and added like by doing `ng-click="show=0;show=1;"`

**Markup**

```
<ul class="list-group  gray-bg">
   <li class="list-group-item link" ng-click="show=0;show=1;">something</li>
   <li class="list-group-item link" ng-click="show=0;show=1;">something</li>
</ul>
```